# R ggplot2 How to Plot Standard Deviation on Bar Chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been searching for a while as to how I can replace the plotting of a confidence interval on a bar chart with a standard deviation. In theory, what I want to do is really basic, but from what I have found, there is no standard deviation option. It seems that, instead, I would have to calculate a separate standard deviation for each group plotted on the chart. Is this correct? Does anyone know of a simple way to plot a standard deviation that doesn't require a separate object to be created?

Here is my code for my chart (you can see it is currently plotting the confidence interval):

```
ggplot(data=subset(df, 
                   !is.na(Job_Is_Complex_Difficult) & 
                   !is.na(ANZSCOGroup) & 
                   !is.na(TOACatSplit))) + 
       aes(x=ANZSCOGroup, 
           y=Job_Is_Complex_Difficult, 
           fill=TOACatSplit) + 
           stat_summary(fun.y=mean, 
                        geom="bar", 
                        position="dodge") + 
       stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, 
       geom="errorbar", 
       width=0.2, 
       position=position_dodge(width=0.90))


    structure(list(Person_ID = c(108306L, 119539L, 117552L, 117553L, 
107685L, 114507L), Age = c(53L, 22L, 68L, 65L, 56L, 45L), Gender = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), Weight = c(96L, 110L, 105L, 63L, 100L, 85L
), Height = c(168L, 180L, 183L, 163L, 188L, 170L), BMI = c(34, 
34, 31.4, 23.7, 28.3, 29.4), WtH_Ratio = c(0.58, 0.64, 0.58, 
0.5, 0.6, 0.61), K10_Risk_Cat = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L), O = c(2.16666666666667, 
5, 5.5, 4.83333333333333, 4.5, 6), C = c(6.16666666666667, 6.16666666666667, 
4.83333333333333, 5.83333333333333, 6, 3.33333333333333), E = c(3.5, 
1.83333333333333, 2.5, 5.16666666666667, 1.83333333333333, 4.83333333333333
), A = c(5.75, 5.5, 5, 6, 4.5, 5), S = c(7, 5, 5, 5.66666666666667, 
3.33333333333333, 4), Part_Full_Time = c(1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Hours_Would_Choose_To_Work = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Hours_Worked = c(50L, 
8L, NA, NA, NA, NA), ANZSCO = c(13L, 22L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Weeks_Worked_Current_Employer = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), Supervises_Others = c(1L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Number_Employed_At_Work = c(9L, 
6L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Pay_Satisfaction = c(5L, 9L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Job_Security_Satisfaction = c(10L, 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Work_Itself_Satisfaction = c(7L, 10L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Hours_Satisfaction = c(7L, 
    9L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Worklife_Satisfaction = c(6L, 10L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Job_Satisfaction = c(7L, 9L, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Looked_For_Job_4_Weeks = c(2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Chance_Voluntary_Leaving_Job_12_Months = c(0L, 
    100L, NA, NA, NA, NA), Planned_Age_Retire = c(60L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), Total_Gross_Amount_Recent_Pay = c(169000L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Pay_Period = c(4L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Has_Credit_Card = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), Freq_Pay_Off_Monthly_Balance = c(4L, 
    NA, 5L, 5L, NA, NA), Number_Children = c(4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    1L, 1L), Frequency_See_Child_Lives_Elsewhere = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), Likelihood_Have_Children_In_Future = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Got_Married = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Got_Separated = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L), Got_Divorced = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Separated_Since_Last_Interview = c(2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Separation_Decision_Maker = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), Minutes_Vigorous_Activity_7_days = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Minutes_Moderate_Activity_7_days = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), Hours_Sleep_Worknight = c(7, 6, NA, NA, NA, NA), Hours_Sleep_Non_Worknight = c(7, 
    7, NA, NA, NA, NA), Life_Satisfaction = c(8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 
    2L, 8L), English_Proficiency = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Children_Ever_Had = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), Time_Married = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Self_Assessed_Health = c(3L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L), Vitality = c(50, 80, 60, 90, 15, 65), 
    Cigarettes_Per_Week = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Standard_Drinks_Per_Day = c(7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L), Frequency_Drinks_Exceeded_Per_Week = c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Member_of_Club = c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L), How_Often_Feel_Rushed = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L), Diets_Last_12_Months = c(2L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L), Satisfaction_With_Weight = c(4L, 3L, 
    3L, 4L, 4L, 5L), Satisfaction_With_Partner = c(NA, NA, 10L, 
    10L, NA, 3L), Satisfaction_With_Children = c(7L, NA, NA, 
    NA, 8L, 9L), Satisfaction_With_Child_Care_Division = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), Satisfaction_With_Household_Task_Division = c(NA, NA, 
    10L, 8L, NA, NA), Share_Housework = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L), Frequency_Socialise_With_Others = c(4L, 3L, 6L, NA, 
    5L, 2L), Life_Event_Past_Year_Got_Married = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), Life_Event_Past_Year_Got_Separated = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Life_Event_Past_Year_Had_Child = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Life_Event_Past_Year_Death_Child_Spouse = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Life_Event_Past_Year_Jail = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Life_Event_Past_Year_Fired_Redundant = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Life_Event_Past_Year_Promoted = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), Hours_Paid_Employment = c(36.5, 8, 15, 
    0, 0, 43), Hours_Work_Travel = c(2.5, 0.666666666666667, 
    8, 0, 0, 2.5), Hours_Household_Errands = c(1.5, 2, 10, 10, 
    7, 3), Hours_Housework = c(7, 3, 10, 55, 12, 11), Hours_Outdoor_Tasks = c(1, 
    0, 15, 30, 0, 5), Hours_Playing_Children = c(0, 0, 0, NA, 
    0, 10), Hours_Volunteer_Work = c(0, 1, 0, NA, 0, 0.416666666666667
    ), Trouble_Getting_Sleep_30_Mins = c(1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
    3L), Could_Not_Pay_Rent_Mortgage = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L), Job_Very_Stressful = c(3L, 2L, 1L, NA, NA, NA), Get_Paid_Fairly = c(4L, 
    6L, 3L, NA, NA, NA), Job_Is_Complex_Difficult = c(6L, 6L, 
    4L, NA, NA, NA), Job_Requires_Learn_New_Skills = c(3L, 6L, 
    5L, NA, NA, NA), I_Use_Skill_In_Job = c(6L, 7L, 3L, NA, NA, 
    NA), I_Have_How_Freedom_In_Job = c(6L, 6L, 4L, NA, NA, NA
    ), I_Have_Say_What_Happens_In_Job = c(7L, 5L, 4L, NA, NA, 
    NA), I_Have_Freedom_When_To_Do_Job = c(2L, 7L, 2L, NA, NA, 
    NA), Choice_In_What_I_Do = c(1L, 6L, 2L, NA, NA, NA), Times_Are_Flexible = c(5L, 
    7L, 2L, NA, NA, NA), Decide_When_To_Take_Break = c(7L, 7L, 
    2L, NA, NA, NA), Same_Thing_Over_And_Over = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
    NA, NA, NA), Variety_And_Interesting_Things = c(5L, 7L, 5L, 
    NA, NA, NA), Requires_Me_Take_Initiative = c(7L, 6L, 6L, 
    NA, NA, NA), Have_To_Work_Fast = c(7L, 4L, 4L, NA, NA, NA
    ), Have_to_Work_Very_Intensely = c(4L, 6L, 6L, NA, NA, NA
    ), Dont_Have_Enough_Time_In_Job = c(7L, 5L, 6L, NA, NA, NA
    ), Parenting_Harder_Than_Thought = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    4L), Worn_Out_From_Children = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2L), 
    Trapped_By_Responsibilities_As_Parent = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 2L), Parenting_More_Work_Than_Pleasure = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 2L), Do_Fair_Share_Looking_After_Children = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L), Miss_Out_Family_Activities = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), Miss_Out_Rewarding_Aspects_Being_Parent = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), AUSEI06_Occupational_Status_Current_Job = c(69.7, 81.9, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), ISIC_Industry_Current_Job = c(75L, 73L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Non_Resident_Child_Maintenance_Paid_Annual = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), Non_Resident_Child_Maintenance_Received_Annual = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), Resident_Child_Maintenance_Paid_Annual = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), Resident_Child_Maintenance_Received_Annual = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), Hours_Per_Week_Worked_In_Last_Job = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), Pay_In_Last_Job_Per_Annum = c(NA_integer_, 
    NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
    ), Days_Paid_Sick_Leave_12_Months = c(40, 0, 0, NA, NA, 5
    ), Days_Paid_Family_Leave_12_Months = c(0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 
    0), Vigorous_Physical_Activity_Min_Week = c(0L, 240L, 120L, 
    0L, 80L, 0L), Moderate_Physical_Activity_Min_Week = c(0L, 
    0L, 180L, 60L, 0L, 180L), Hours_Sleep_Per_Week = c(48, 47, 
    51, 55, 25, 34), SEIFA_Decile_Socio_Economic = c(10L, 5L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 10L), SEIFA_Decile_Economic_Resources = c(9L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L), SEIFA_Decile_Education_Occupation = c(10L, 
    9L, 6L, 6L, 9L, 10L), Parents_Separated = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, NA), Age_Parents_Separated = c(8L, 15L, 30L, NA, NA, 
    6L), Highest_Education = c(9L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 8L), Times_Married = c(2L, 
    0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), B5_Talkative = c(4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 
    6L), B5_Sympathetic = c(6L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L), B5_Orderly = c(6L, 
    7L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 2L), B5_Envious = c(1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 5L
    ), B5_Deep = c(1L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 6L), B5_Withdrawn = c(1L, 
    6L, 6L, 2L, 6L, 4L), B5_Harsh = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 5L), 
    B5_Systematic = c(5L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 2L), B5_Moody = c(1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 4L), B5_Philosophical = c(1L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 
    3L, 6L), B5_Bashful = c(7, 2, 6, 5, 3, 4), B5_Kind = c(6L, 
    6L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 6L), B5_Inefficient = c(7, 6, 4, 5, 6, 6), 
    B5_Touchy = c(1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 5L), B5_Creative = c(1L, 
    5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L), B5_Quiet = c(3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 4), B5_Cooperative = c(5L, 
    6L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 3L), B5_Sloppy = c(6, 6, 4, 7, 6, 5), B5_Jealous = c(1L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 5L), B5_Intellectual = c(5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
    6L, 5L), B5_Extroverted = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 5L), B5_Cold = c(1L, 
    3L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 2L), B5_Disorganised = c(7, 6, 5, 7, 6, 2
    ), B5_Temperamental = c(1L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L), B5_Complex = c(1L, 
    6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 6L), B5_Shy = c(3, 1, 1, 5, 2, 5), B5_Warm = c(6L, 
    5L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L), B5_Efficient = c(6L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
    3L), B5_Fretful = c(1L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 1L), B5_Imaginative = c(4L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L), B5_Enthusiastic = c(6L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 
    2L, 7L), B5_Selfish = c(1L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), B5_Careless = c(1L, 
    2L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L), B5_Calm = c(6L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 2L, 4L), 
    B5_Traditional = c(2L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 5L), B5_Lively = c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 6L, 2L, 5L), AgeGroup = structure(c(9L, 3L, 12L, 
    12L, 10L, 8L), .Label = c("10-14", "15-19", "20-24", "25-29", 
    "30-34", "35-39", "40-44", "45-49", "50-54", "55-59", "60-64", 
    "65-69", "70-74", "75-79", "80-84", "85-89", "90-94", "95-99", 
    "100-104", "105-109", "110-114", "115-119"), class = "factor"), 
    GenderFactor = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Male", 
    "Female"), class = "factor"), OCat = structure(c(1L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Closed", "Average", "Open"), class = "factor"), 
    CCat = structure(c(3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Lazy", 
    "Average", "Conscientious"), class = "factor"), ECat = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Introvert", "Ambivert", 
    "Extravert"), class = "factor"), ACat = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Disagreeable", "Average", "Agreeable"
    ), class = "factor"), SCat = structure(c(3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L), .Label = c("Neurotic", "Average", "Stable"), class = "factor"), 
    OCatSplit = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Closed", 
    "Open"), class = "factor"), CCatSplit = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Lazy", "Conscientious"), class = "factor"), 
    ECatSplit = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Introvert", 
    "Extravert"), class = "factor"), ACatSplit = structure(c(2L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Disagreeable", "Agreeable"
    ), class = "factor"), SCatSplit = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Neurotic", "Stable"), class = "factor"), 
    Stability = c(4.125, 4.8125, 4.1875, 4.5625, 5.125, 4), TOA = c(2.83333333333333, 
    3.41666666666667, 4, 5, 3.16666666666667, 5.41666666666667
    ), A2 = c(2.25, 2.5, 3, 2, 3.5, 3), TOA2 = c(2.54166666666667, 
    2.95833333333333, 3.5, 3.5, 3.33333333333333, 4.20833333333333
    ), TOACat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Low ToA", 
    "Ave TOA", "High TOA"), class = "factor"), TOACatSplit = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Low TOA", "High TOA"), class = "factor"), 
    Ambiguity = c(5.5, 5.66666666666667, 4.66666666666667, NA, 
    NA, NA), Autonomy = c(4.66666666666667, 6.33333333333333, 
    2.66666666666667, NA, NA, NA), ANZSCO10 = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("ANZSCO10", "Other"), class = "factor"), 
    ANZSCO20 = structure(c(2L, 1L, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("ANZSCO20", 
    "Other"), class = "factor"), ANZSCO30 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("ANZSCO30", "Other"), class = "factor"), 
    ANZSCO40 = structure(c(2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("ANZSCO40", 
    "Other"), class = "factor"), ANZSCO50 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("ANZSCO50", "Other"), class = "factor"), 
    ANZSCO60 = structure(c(2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("ANZSCO60", 
    "Other"), class = "factor"), ANZSCO70 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("ANZSCO70", "Other"), class = "factor"), 
    ANZSCO80 = structure(c(2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("ANZSCO80", 
    "Other"), class = "factor"), ANZSCOGroup = structure(c(1L, 
    2L, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("G10", "G20", "G30", "G40", 
    "G50", "G60", "G70", "G80"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Difficult to answer without seeing some or all of `df`.

Comment: Why? It would take me many hours to try and figure out how to extract data from my dataset (N=9000) to post on to Stack Overflow. I have read the post about reproducing an example but forget it - way too complicated for what should be a simple problem.

Comment: Extracting your data is as simple as dput(head(df)), where df is your dataframe. Reproducing an example on SO is simple once you know how to do it (just like your problem). Without an idea of how the data is structured, it is difficult for others to understand your problem or to help you.

Comment: OK let me give that a crack...

Comment: OK done - thanks for the tip. As you say, that was nice and painless.

Comment: instead of `mean_cl_boot` you can use `mean_sdl`

Comment: Perfect! That was all I needed. Thanks very much! Do you want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `mean_sdl` instead of `mean_cl_boot`